# Overwrite Parent style on css

Tags: html, css

I have the following scenario.

I need to customize all links on a website to have an orange background.

```
.have-all-links-orange a{
    background-color: #F59522;
}
```

however when I do this all images inside an A get the same background,
I tried with this but didn't do the trick

```
.have-all-links-orange a img{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Any ideas on how may I fix this?

#### UPDATE

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/azweig/616d530s/)

Comment: Are you sure the images don't just have transparent backgrounds?

Comment: well your code would not affect images, are your images png? if so do they have transparent background at some part of the image? What is the background colour of the body? set that colour as the img background colour

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the markup too or at the very least a screenshot.

Comment: @JordanS 100% sure

Comment: @JosephMarikle will do

Comment: @JosephMarikle added the link :) https://jsfiddle.net/azweig/616d530s/

Comment: @Saikios https://jsfiddle.net/616d530s/1/ The image doesn't have an orange background, it's just in the same line as the image so it's rendering in such a way that it appears to have an orange background. Putting the image into a block element clears that out.

Comment: check the shadow of the image or remove the text the background corresponds to the image not to the text, I believe that what's going on is that it's adding the transparent to the img and the a is having an orange

and that's why it's surrounding the image with the background with orange that's why I would like to overwrite it@JordanS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem:

because `img` is by default an inline element therefore creates a gap and has `vertical-align:baseline` by default.

## Solution

- set `display:block` in `img`

```css
.have-all-links-orange a {
  background-color: #F59522;
}

.have-all-links-orange a img {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="have-all-links-orange">
  <a href="www.google.com">
    <img src="https://www.google.com.pe/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
    <br />
    <a href="http://www.google.com">click here<a>
<div>
```

Comment: @Saikios  Why don't just remove the image and  put only the donate text. That will correspond with your other links. Or just format that link to look like your image

Comment: @blecaf because that issue affects all images, not just that one :)

Answer (score 1):

make the image a block element.

```
.have-all-links-orange a img {
    display: block;
     background-color: transparent;/**You don't need this**/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
.have-all-links-orange a img {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: block;
}
```

[Here is a forked fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y4f54vz6/)

[How to get anchor tag on background image of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936719/how-to-get-anchor-tag-on-background-image-of-div)

Answer (score -1):

Hm.. maybe like this? You did say "ALL of the links to have oragne background".

```
a {
 background-color: #F59522;
}
```

Comment: The orange part is working, the part that isn't working is the one that overwrite this property

Comment: background-color:  #F59522 !important; ?

Comment: Then I don't understand your question then. You said "you need to have all links on a website to have an orange background" and the code you provided does that. Then you said "the part that isn't working is the one that overwrite this property" and then again you said "again, the orange is working". I don't understand you.

Answer (score -1):

If you have to have your images in a different display, you can always use jquery to get rid of the color:

https://jsfiddle.net/616d530s/2/

```
$('.have-all-links-orange a img').closest('a').css('background', 'transparent');
```